How can I completely uninstall all versions of Opera?
I have installed Opera from the Snap Store and from a .deb file.
Opera is now not playing videos from multiple sites that used to work OK, and still work in other browsers.
I've tried tinkering with it, but don't really know what I'm doing. So now I would like to uninstall both versions and everything to do with Opera in order that I can start again with a clean sheet.
How can I completely uninstall everything Opera from my system?
I've tried uninstalling from the Snap Store, but that leaves an entry in my App drawer.
How can I clear this?
Haven't yet done anything to try to uninstall the .deb version, how would I do this?
How can I then clear anything that might be left in the App drawer (Show Applications)?

You can use many package managers to add/install/remove deb files, eg. I'd likely use aptitude for that, or just remove it via apt remove... just as you can use snap remove to remove snap packages. The thing is to use the reverse of how it was installed; so ask the installer (or check your install logs) for how it was installed; as if a source was added you may wish to remove that too.

Thanks @gulverc
Managed to uninstall both versions, then downloaded .deb package and went to reinstall via GDebi which advised downloading from Snap, which I did, but videos still not playing.
